# EF core unoptimized translation partition by

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm building an r/place like application.

I've got the following database (postgresql) [image: table structure].

In order to fetch only the last pixel per coordinate, I made this sql query

```sql
select c.id, p.x, p.y, p.color from dbo.canvas c
inner join (
    select row_number() over (partition by p.x, p.y order by p."canvasId" desc) n, *
    from dbo.pixels p

-- filter on id here to optimize lookup
    where p."canvasId" = :canvasId
) p on n = 1

where c.id = :canvasId;
```

I tried to replicate it using Ef core and LinQ, which has brought me up to this

```cs
_context.Canvas
    .Where(c => c.Id == canvasId)
    .Select(
        c => new
        {
            Canvas = c,
            Pixels = c.Pixels
                .GroupBy(p => new { p.X, p.Y })
                .Select(
                    g => g
                        .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)
                        .First()
                ))
        })
```

Which is translated to

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.cooldown, c.height, c.width, t2.id, t2."authorId", t2."canvasId", t2.color, t2."createdAt", t2.x, t2.y, t2.x0, t2.y0
FROM dbo.canvas AS c
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT t0.id, t0."authorId", t0."canvasId", t0.color, t0."createdAt", t0.x, t0.y, t.x AS x0, t.y AS y0
    FROM (
        SELECT p.x, p.y
        FROM dbo.pixels AS p
        WHERE c.id = p."canvasId"
        GROUP BY p.x, p.y
    ) AS t
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT t1.id, t1."authorId", t1."canvasId", t1.color, t1."createdAt", t1.x, t1.y
        FROM (
            SELECT p0.id, p0."authorId", p0."canvasId", p0.color, p0."createdAt", p0.x, p0.y, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p0.x, p0.y ORDER BY p0."createdAt" DESC) AS row
            FROM dbo.pixels AS p0
            WHERE c.id = p0."canvasId"
        ) AS t1
        WHERE t1.row <= 1
    ) AS t0 ON t.x = t0.x AND t.y = t0.y
) AS t2 ON TRUE
WHERE c.id = @__canvasId_0
```

Both return the same results but the latest takes ~5 secs to perform instead of ~200ms for the first one. (Over 1M rows)

So I'm wondering if there is a workaraound to tell EF to not do those useless joins and get close to what I did in plain sql.

Comment: For complex queries i would not use ef.

Comment: @Magnus id like to use it for column and table name mapping instead of having to update each of my queries when a change is made

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. I think it is best what you can do with EF Core's LINQ translator. Other solutions may require third party extensions.

```cs
// prepare joined and filtered query
var rawQuery = 
    from c in _context.Canvas
    where c.Id == canvasId
    from p in c.Pixels
    select new
    {
        Canvas = c,
        Pixel = p
    };

// query flattened Canvas and Pixel pairs
var rawResult = 
    from d in rawQuery.Select(d => new { d.Canvas.Id, d.Pixel.X, d.Pixel.Y })
        .Distinct()
    from r in rawQuery
        .Where(r => r.Canvas.Id == d.Id && p.Pixel.X == d.X && p.Pixel.Y == d.Y)
        .OrderByDescending(r => r.Pixel.CreatedAt)
        .Take(1)
    select new
    {
        r.Canvas,
        r.Pixel
    }
    
// perform grouping on the client side
var result = rawResult.AsEnumerable() 
    .GroupBy(r => r.Canvas)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Canvas = g.Key,
        Pixels = g.Select(x = x.Pixel).Tolist()
    })
    .ToList();
```